# Sqlcmd export data to csv using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server and export data out to `.csv` (using "Save Result As"), the output `.csv` was formatted very nicely.

My goal is to extract data in this format, with the headers:

```
PK1,2005/010,#,Not Analysed,CVOI001,C Voice 001 Test Account,PI -Local,11/11/2019,-571.430,C,T00012                        
PK1,2005/010,#,Not Analysed,32400,Annual bonus,PI -Local,11/11/2019,571.430,D,T00012
```

But when I use `sqlcmd` to extract data from the same stored procedure (the goal is to automate this extraction task), the format is very different with "------" to separate the headers and a lot of padding in the fields. Sorry I cannot post the headers as the post will exceed the character limit.

Here's my code and the current output. Is there anything I should change?

```
sqlcmd -S SUNSERVER -E -Q "Exec SunSystemsData.[dbo].[z_UniFocusExtract] $(BUCode), $(LCode), $(TCodeNo), $(NoDayBack)" 
       -v BUCode='PK1' LCode='ANAL_T1' TCodeNo='2' NoDayBack='-100' -s "," -o "C:/Test/Test.csv"
```

```
PK1    ,2005/010,#              ,Not Analysed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ,CVOI001        ,C Voice 001 Test Account                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ,PI -Local                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ,11/11/2019          ,              -571.430,C  ,T00012                        
PK1    ,2005/010,#              ,Not Analysed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ,32400          ,Annual bonus                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ,PI -Local                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ,11/11/2019          ,               571.430,D  ,T00012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more parameter to remove the headers from the csv file generated.

[Sqlcmd msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

`-h-1 removes column name headers from the result`

> -h headers
>   Specifies the number of rows to print between the column headings. The default is to print headings one time for each set of
>   query results. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable
>   SQLCMDHEADERS. Use -1 to specify that headers not be printed. Any
>   value that is not valid causes sqlcmd to generate an error message and
>   then exit.

For removing the extra padding spaces in the column width, add -W parameter. I have tested it. It is working fine.

> -W This option removes trailing spaces from a column. Use this option together with the -s option when preparing data that is to be exported
>   to another application. Cannot be used with the -y or -Y options.

Comment: Thanks. But actually what I would want is to add the headers and remove the padding between the fields.

Comment: @anhtle, I have updated my answer. You need to add -W option

Comment: thanks! It's working now. Really appreciate your help